# Docker installation fails on Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, powershell, containers, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install Docker on my Windows server 2016 using PowerShell, but I'm encountering an issue. Here's the command I'm using:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
 
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
 
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Force

Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

Here is the Error

```
WARNING: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\AZUREL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\DockerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json' because it does not exist.
WARNING: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'downloadURL' because it is an empty string.
WARNING: The property 'AbsoluteUri' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
WARNING: The property 'RequestMessage' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'docker'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package
sources.
At line:9 char:1
+ Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Comment: Better use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass Process` to allow everything in the current window/process

Answer (score 0):

1. The DockerMsftProvider is down [github](https://github.com/OneGet/MicrosoftDockerProvider).
2. You can use [install-docker-ce.ps1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/Main/helpful_tools/Install-DockerCE/install-docker-ce.ps1) from [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce), and run it will PowerShell **64bit**

   .\install-docker-ce.ps1

   But the script will install the latest version(V24), it won't work on Windows Server 2016.
3. So you must manually install from [binary](https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64?_gl=1*1h3jfax*_ga*MTQ4NDAxNTI4Ni4xNzAwMTA3OTE4*_ga_XJWPQMJYHQ*MTcwMTgyNjU1MC44LjEuMTcwMTgyNzc4Ny41OC4wLjA.), the latest work version is 20.10.9

   C:> Expand-Archive /path/to/.zip -DestinationPath $Env:ProgramFiles

   C:> &$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\dockerd --register-service

[Details of install from binary](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/)

PS. Most docker image won't run under Windows Server 2016, it's better to move to Windows Server 2019